# How can I consume table data in JSON format from Postman with a modular Spring Boot application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

i am looking to use springboot to make a java rest app to consume table data in a json format from postman. each table might be a different length of columns and I am looking to make it modular. what i have so far in my java app is the controller, table DTO  and a row DTO (Data transfer object) if i could be shown what would be the best way and maybe an explanation of how the data is being consumed that would help. this is my first time working with springboot and post man.

```
package com.example.restservice.controller;

import com.example.restservice.*;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

@RestController
public class TableCollectionController {



    @GetMapping("/getTable")
    public Table table(){
        Table table = new Table();
        table.setTableName("Name");
        table.setAction("Action");

        List columns = new ArrayList();
        Column column = new Column();
        column.setName("Name");
        column.setValue("Value");
        columns.add(column);
        columns.add(column);
        columns.add(column);
        columns.add(column);
        table.setColumns(columns);
        return table;
        
    }
    @PostMapping("/postTable")
    public Table table(@RequestBody Table table1){
        System.out.println(table1.getTableName());
        System.out.println(table1.getAction());
        System.out.println(table1.getColumns());
        return table1;
    }
```

a table class

```
package com.example.restservice;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Table {

     String tableName;
     String action;
     List columns; //object list


}
```

and a row class

```
package com.example.restservice;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Row {

    public String name;

    public String value;


}
```

all i know is that i will be getting json data in the format below i know a little java but am still pretty new.

```
{
    "tablename": "tablesName",
    "action": "ADD",
    "data": [
        {
            "columnName": "column1",
            "Value": "valueName"
        },
        {
            "columnName": "column2",
            "Value": "123-1ad-4bc"
        },
        {
            "columnName": "column3",
            "Value": "valueName"
        },
        etc....
    ]
}
```

so far what i have tried is developing an app that has allowed me to use postman to get a json and update the data in json which works but only as a single column item. if i try to duplicated the items column name and value it gives me an error that they are duplicated and no immediate fix.

--update-- was able to add more items using an array and when i complete a post and add more json objects to the columns it does add more items

Comment: Your `@PostMapping` method needs two things: the argument needs to be annotated with `@RequestBody`, and the `@PostMapping` annotation needs to specify that it consumes `application/json`.

Comment: yeah thanks i just saw that when re running the code made a few changes and was about to update the issue. so i was able to get my code with a array list and set up to add 4 new columns but that still limits what i am trying to do is there a way to not specify how many objects the array list can contain? so it keeps making a new array item?.

Comment: I think i have fixed my issue with the array list as i can keep adding new objects to the list array. if anyone else knows of a better way please feel free to post and let me know.